# JS Promises - Angular - Can then be used on any function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, es6-promise

I want to ask can `then()` be used on any function?

In my Angular app I'm seeing an error ('cannot read property then of undefined') when trying to use `then`.

For example I have this function:

```
self.getCommentsData = function() {
  commentsService.getComments($routeParams.id)
  .then(function (data){
    //Do some stuff and at the end push to a scope array
    $scope.commentsList.push(someValue);
  });
}
```

And later on I want to call this method and then (and only then) call another line of code once thats completed, which is were I'm using the `then`:

```
self.getCommentsData()
      .then(function(){
        $location.hash('goTotrue');
        $anchorScroll();
});
```

This gives me an error - wondering what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: .then is not a magic, its just available on Promises alike objects only.

Answer (score 3):

you should return promise in function for chain

```
self.getCommentsData = function() {
  return commentsService.getComments($routeParams.id)
  .then(function (data){
    //Do some stuff and at the end push to a scope array
    $scope.commentsList.push(someValue);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks - so is it as simple as adding a `return`?

Answer (score 1):

`.then()` can't be used on any function. Only a function that returns some form of a Promise.

I would review the MDN docs on [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [Promise.prototype.then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), and Promises in Angular using [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

In your case, only `commentsService.getComments($routeParams.id)` returns a Promise, so `.then()` can be called on it.

`commentsService.getComments($routeParams.id).then()` also returns a Promise that resolves after the function in the `.then()` block runs, therefore you can simply add a `return` to chain the Promise created.
It would be the same as calling:

```
commentsService.getComments($routeParams.id).then().then();
```

Your code with `return` added:

```
  self.getCommentsData = function() {
    return commentsService.getComments($routeParams.id)
      .then(function (data){
        //Do some stuff and at the end push to a scope array
        $scope.commentsList.push(someValue);
      });
}
```

Comment: But that method *could* return the promise, allowing it to be further chained. This is a half answer.

Comment: Thanks - I understand now, so in the answer above by @aseferov - is solving this as simple as adding a `return`

Comment: @Jamiec. I agree. Answer updated. I was a little confused by the question. Couldn't determine whether or not he wanted that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a promise, if you don't, this error will still appear. If you see the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), you can find this:

> The purpose of the deferred object is to expose the associated
>   Promise instance as well as APIs that can be used for signaling the
>   successful or unsuccessful completion, as well as the status of the
>   task

To illustrate this, I've made this snippet:

```js
angular
  .module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", myCtrl)
  .service("myService", myService)
  
  myCtrl.$inject  = ["myService"];
  myService.$inject  = ["$q", "$timeout"];
  
  function myCtrl(myService){
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = [{user: "empty"}, {user: "empty"}, {user: "empty"}]
    vm.message = "Just wait 3 seconds to retrieve the data";
    
    myService.myPromise().then(function(res){
      //success case. The promise has been resolved
      vm.data = res;
      vm.message = "Promise resolved!";
      console.log("resultado");
      console.log(res);
    });
    
    
  }
  
  function myService($q, $timeout){
    this.myPromise = function(){
      var promiseObj = $q.defer(); //promise
      var dummyData = [{user: 1}, {user: 2}, {user: 3}];
      
      //this timeout is to ilustrate that the promise may take some time
      //you don't need to use the $timeout service
      $timeout(function(){
        promiseObj.resolve(dummyData); //promise resolved
      }, 3000);
      
      //promise resolved
      return promiseObj.promise;
      
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.14" data-semver="1.3.14" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
  <h1>Promise test</h1>
  <h2>Dummy data</h2>
  <h4>{{ctrl.message}}</h4>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="data in ctrl.data">{{data.user}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

No, you can only use then on $promise.

So only this will work:

```
commentsService.getComments($routeParams.id).then(function (data){
    $scope.commentsList.push(someValue);
});
```